# accessing props from interact js "interact('.dropzone').dropzone

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I try to access the props inside the ondrop function (and maybe later others)
But I can't access the props from there. Here is the code

'''interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
    // minimum percentage from the draggable to be accepted in the dropzone
    overlap: 1,

```
// listen for drop related events:

ondropactivate: function (event) {
    // add active dropzone feedback
    event.target.classList.add('drop-active')
},
ondragenter: function (event) {
    var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget
    var dropzoneElement = event.target

    // feedback the possibility of a drop
    dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target')
    draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop')
},
ondragleave: function (event) {
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target')
    event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop')
},
ondrop: function (event) {
    //TODO: rerender widget dragables, save position into store
    let availableOptions = JSON.parse(event.dragEvent.currentTarget.dataset.options).avalibaleOptions
    for( let i=0 ; i < availableOptions ; i++ ) {
        this.props.change(availableOptions);
    }
    console.log("position: ", event.dragEvent.rect)
    console.log("welche Daten sind enthalten?", JSON.parse(event.dragEvent.currentTarget.dataset.options) )
    //löschen und neu erstellen? in den state schreiben reicht? ...
},
ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
    // remove active dropzone feedback
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-active')
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target')
}
```

})'''
this.props.change(availableOptions) is a reducer. It is meant to change the store according to the data and the coordinates of the div.

I haven't found any clue how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, I just imported store and directly used store.dispatch()...